MudBlazor MudDataGrid Multi-line Edit
How do you implement a multi-line text edit field (MudTextField) in the data grids edit form?
I cannot find any guidance on how to implement this.
I am using the form edit mode, not the in-line editor.  I tried an edit template but the MudTextField  did not show up at all in the edit form.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

As you said you tried, you can use an EditTemplate
    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Name" >
        <EditTemplate>
            <MudTextField MaxLines="4" @bind-Value="@context.Item.Name" Variant="Variant.Outlined" AutoGrow/>
        </EditTemplate>
    </PropertyColumn>

You can either use AutoGrow or Lines="{value greater than 1}" to use multilines
MudSnippet
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
@inject HttpClient httpClient
    
    <MudDataGrid T="Element" Items="@Elements.Take(4)" ReadOnly="false" EditMode="@DataGridEditMode.Form"
        Bordered="true" Dense="true">
        <Columns>
            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Number" Title="Nr" IsEditable="false" />
            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Sign" >
                <EditTemplate>
                    <MudTextField MaxLines="4" @bind-Value="@context.Item.Sign" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Lines="2"/>
                </EditTemplate>
            </PropertyColumn>
            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Name" >
                <EditTemplate>
                    <MudTextField MaxLines="4" @bind-Value="@context.Item.Name" Variant="Variant.Outlined" AutoGrow/>
                </EditTemplate>
            </PropertyColumn>
            <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Molar" Title="Molar mass" />
            <TemplateColumn CellClass="d-flex justify-end">
                <CellTemplate>
                    <MudIconButton Size="@Size.Small" Icon="@Icons.Material.Outlined.Edit" OnClick="@context.Actions.StartEditingItemAsync" />
                </CellTemplate>
            </TemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MudDataGrid>
    
    @code {
        private IEnumerable<Element> Elements = new List<Element>();
    
        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            Elements = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Element>>("webapi/periodictable");
        }

        public class Element
        {
            public string Group { get; set; }
            public int Position { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Number { get; set; }
    
            [JsonPropertyName("small")]
            public string Sign { get; set; }
            public double Molar { get; set; }
            public IList<int> Electrons { get; set; }
    
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return $"{Sign} - {Name}";
            }
        }
    }

